# Slide and Show Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-8

What is that Navigation style that is implemented in 75% of all WP7 apps such as email, Images ,where you slide left and right, and as you do, you can see half of one page and half of the other, as one page fades out and the other fades , as if somehow all pages where one big circular roll.Here i was used pivot control for swipe images one by one.

I have tried the slide transition, but it definitely does a jagged approach when sliding out of one and sliding into the other, and you don't see the two merged together.how to solve these issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `Panorama` page or a page with a `Pivot` control.

Comment: I am trying to avoid space between 2 pivot items but not able to solve . how to set minimum space between swiping one item to next or vice versa, When user swipes it is displaying first image to next image or preview image but here there is some bug i.s. when user swipes one image then it displays one item gap between 2 pivot items and after that followed by next pivot items. How to resolve this?

Comment: You could stretch the picture width, but as far as I know, you can't change the pivot width.

Comment: Means not possible to avoid  one item gap between 2 pivot items and after that followed by next pivot items ?

Comment: Well, pivot is a choice but I don't think it is best. You might have to end up in making your own user control to handle your case of image showing. Initially, you asked for a solution which Panorama or Pivot are okay but now you're saying you need these for images. If you stretch the images , then it will be okay. If not, you need to design a custom user control for your problem.